# FB.login popup no longer working on Safari mac?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari

Anyone else no longer getting popups in Safari?

Here's some sample code that does not work in Safari. It is launched by a click on link so the popup blocker shouldn't block it. Any ideas why it does?

Online example here:

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/fbtest.html

Note that this will not run through the expected behavior since it's on another domain and has an incorrect app ID. But the only thing that matters for this example is the showing of the popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fbLoaded = false;
var doReLogin = true;

function createAccessToken(){   
if (!fbLoaded) {
    FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxx', // App ID
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
}

fbLoaded = true;

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {      
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        getExtendedAccessToken(response.authResponse);
    } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                if (response.authResponse && response.authResponse.accessToken) {
                    getExtendedAccessToken(response.authResponse);
                } else {
                    alert('You cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            } else {
                alert('To use you have to create an access token.');
            }
        }, {scope: 'read_stream'});
    }
 }, true);
}

function getExtendedAccessToken() {
}
</script>

<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" onclick="createAccessToken();return false;" class="connect">Connect With FaceBook</a></p>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with all the required libraries included?

Comment: @collindo couldn't get it working on jsfiddle, so placed it online on another domain. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your settings regarding blocking pop-up window?
This issue: [Facebook Login not open in Safari/ iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493198) the same as you have, I guess.